# Pagination result with table helper

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, helper

Controller:

```
$data['result'] = $this->pagination_model->search($searchterm,$limit);
```

Model:

```
public function search($searchterm,$limit)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM recipe 
                WHERE name LIKE '%" . $searchterm . "%' LIMIT " .$limit . ",2";
        $q = $this->db->query($sql);
        if($q->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            foreach($q->result() as $row)
            {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

If I print the result using foreach loop it would work, but when I try to print it with table helper:

`$this->table->generate($result);` <---`$result` = From controller.

It will post an error when trying to print the result,

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\www\Finals\system\libraries\Table.php on line 178

Since that area is restricted, I can't determine why it won't accept the data. Anyone who's knowledgeable with table library could clarify what type of data table accepts.

I could just use the foreach method in printing, but I am keen on learning and using ci helpers.

EDIT: additional info,

Controller: From simply listing all records on db using pagination. Above is when search filter is done.

```
$data['records'] = $this->db->get('recipe', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
```

The table helper accepts the data and prints it.

```
$This->table->generate($records);
```

Is there any difference to both returned data sets.

Will try to find out with `print_r()`

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter returns result rows as objects, not arrays. From the [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html):

> **result()**
>
> ---
>
> This function returns the query result as an array of objects, or an
>   empty array on failure.

You'll have to access the fields using the following notation:

```
foreach($q->result() as $row)
{
    $data[] = $row->data;
}
```

or if you really want an array instead you can use:

```
$q->result_array()
```

which would return the same information as an associative array.

Comment: $data[] = $row->data; --> from my model right?

returns an error of Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$data

Comment: `$row->data` doesn't mean exactly write `data` in you code. what do have in you database?! for example `name` . you have to use `$row->name`

Comment: or you can change your query code to `foreach($q->result_array() as $row)` instead of `foreach($q->result() as $row)`

Comment: If i were to change my current one and do display the result using $this->table->generate()

Is there anyway i could put the result inside an anchor tag. like

 <?=anchor('showrecipe/'.$r->id,$r->name);?>

as when result is posted i need to link it for users to view the complete detail of that recipe.